# For Loop not Working In laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop, eloquent

For Loop Not Working $AllPathsTasgs  have 2 arrays So count($AllPathsTasgs) Will return 2 my and I'm returning 2 paths So it Should first use

```
$x == 0
```

Then Should use

```
$x == 1
```

but it uses

```
$x == 1
```

For the Tow, paths don't know Why

although I have use   dd($x); and it returns $x  correctly

any Help Please

```
foreach ($paths as $path){
    $AllPathsTasgs[]  = $path->pathtags->pluck('name');
}

$posts3 = Path::with(['ProgrammingField','pathtags' => function ($q) use ($AllPathsTasgs) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($AllPathsTasgs); $x++) {
        if ($x == 0) {
            $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($AllPathsTasgs, $x) {
                $q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                    ->whereDoesntHave('tasktags', function ($query) use ($AllPathsTasgs, $x) {
                        $query->whereNotIn('name', $AllPathsTasgs[0]);
                    })->with('tasktags')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
            }]);
        }

        if ($x == 1) {
            $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($AllPathsTasgs, $x) {
                $q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                    ->whereDoesntHave('tasktags', function ($query) use ($AllPathsTasgs, $x) {
                        $query->whereNotIn('name', $AllPathsTasgs[1]);
                    })->with('tasktags')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
            }]);
        }
    }
}])->whereIn('id',$pathId)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

write this inside the loop and we're outside like that.

```
foreach ($paths as $path){
                $AllPathsTasgs[]  = $path->pathtags->pluck('name');    
        $posts3 = Path::with(['ProgrammingField','pathtags' => function ($q) use ($AllPathsTasgs) {
                    for ($x = 0; $x < count($AllPathsTasgs); $x++) {
                        if ($x == 0 ){

                    $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($AllPathsTasgs,$x)  {

                        $q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')

                    ->whereDoesntHave('tasktags', function ($query) use ($AllPathsTasgs,$x) {
                               $query->whereNotIn('name', $AllPathsTasgs[0]);

                    })->with('tasktags')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');   
                }]);
            }             
            if ($x == 1 ){

                $q->with(['Tasks' => function ($q) use ($AllPathsTasgs,$x)  {

                    $q->has('tasktags', '=', 2)
                ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')

                ->whereDoesntHave('tasktags', function ($query) use ($AllPathsTasgs,$x) {
                           $query->whereNotIn('name', $AllPathsTasgs[1]);


                })->with('tasktags')->orderBy('id', 'ASC');


            }]);
        }
```

Comment: i get same result  please  help

Comment: i have tried to put for loop out the full path code put same result